# How to find a particular grand parent by Id and get value of its particular children by certain class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent, children

I have a dynamic div

```
<div class="illustartionWrap" id="illustartionWrapId">
     <div class="illusList illusListTop" id="illusList_heading">
            <span class="fileName">File Name</span>
            <span class="fileDesc">Description</span>
            <span class="fileSize">File Size</span>
            <span class="fileDownload">Download</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="illusList">
            <span class="fileName">fileTitle</span>
            <span class="fileDesc">fileDesc</span>
            <span class="fileSize">1.18 MB</span>
            <span class="fileDownload">
                <a href="http://myfile/file.txt">
                    <img src="/sites/all/themes/petheme/images/myimage.png">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img id="illFile_6" class="illDeleteFile" src="/sites/all/themes/petheme/images/icons/deleteButton.png">//clicking it to delete the file from db 
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
 </div>
```

How to get the parents of this delete button and find the filetitle class to get the title of the file.

Below is click handler which I wrote

```
/**delete function for my page**/
    jQuery(".illDeleteFile").on("click", function() {
        var illDeleteId = jQuery(this).attr("id").split("_");
        var illFileTitle = jQuery(this).parent("#illusList").children(".fileName").val();

        alert (illFileTitle);
});
```

I checked with jQuery Parent() , Parents() and children() and also find() but I am getting undefined mostly and not getting the title.

How to achieve this?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/ywhbd9ut/14/) : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/ywhbd9ut/14/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: I don't see any `filetitle` classed elements in your example?

Comment: `.fileName` class is having fileTitle... sorry for the confusion

Comment: thanks @FelixKling : `closet` worked :) ... see here http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/ywhbd9ut/24/

Comment: @FelixKling : thanks for helping me. one quick question, why does `closest` not work with `id` --> http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/ywhbd9ut/29/

Comment: Good question. It seems like a bug to me. However, since IDs are supposed to be unique in a document, `$('#id')` would work in that case as well.

Comment: @hitesh Because the element with id `illusList_heading` is not a parent of the second row; it's a parent of the first row. Try `.closest('#illustartionWrapId')` instead.

Comment: @Pluto - thanks .... you are right .. http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/uvfwjjqx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this,

```
jQuery(".illDeleteFile").on("click", function() {
    var illFileTitle =jQuery(this).closest(".illusList").find(".fileName").html();
    alert (illFileTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use:

```
var illFileTitle = jQuery(this).closest(".illusList").find(".fileName").text();

alert(illFileTitle);
```